# Jquery how to translate text date with momentjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have a bunch of `<p>`-tags which each has a date inside. Now I want to translate those to another format using `momentjs` but it doesn't really work.

```
<div class="container">

  <p class="ordered">2018-10-01</p>

  <p class="ordered">2018-10-02</p>

  <p class="ordered">2018-10-03</p>
</div>
```

and my js file:

```
$(".ordered").each(item => {
  let formatted_order_date = moment(item).locale("de").format("Do MMM");
});
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rd3jb8eL/)

So, can someone tell me what is the issue here?

Comment: It is added in the resurces

Comment: when you do a console.log(item) you see, that it's 0, 1, 2 - but _not_ the datestring. So moment(item) will be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item in your example is not the datestring, but is the index.
The callback in each has two params: the index, and the item (as second): `each((i,item) ...`
The item then is the complete html element, so we need to get the 'value' (the inner html) out of it:
`$(item).html()`

```
$(".is-ordered").each((i,item) => {
  // console.log($(item).html());
  let datestring = $(item).html();
  let formatted_order_date = new moment(datestring)
  .locale("de")
  .format("Do MMM");
  console.log(formatted_order_date); // 3rd Oct
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, I see... Thanks alot! :-)

Comment: So I added `$(item).html(formatted_order_date)` now it shows the date in the desired format

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `item`, try using `$(this)`.

```
$(".ordered").each(() => {
  const formatted_order_date = moment($(this).text().trim()).locale("de").format("Do MMM");
  $(this).text(formatted_order_date);
});
```